# How to apply distinct in one column, while getting few other columns from table

Tags: postgresql

How to apply distinct in one column, while getting few other columns from table.

For example, something like this,

`Select distinct date(date0), name from note`

So the goal here is to get all the results, for different days(distinct date(date0))

Sample data:

| Date | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 01st Jan 2021 | Bohemian |
| 01st Jan 2021 | Bohemian |
| 01st Jan 2021 | Bohemian |
| 02nd Jan 2021 | Jack |
| 03rd Jan 2021 | John |

Expected Results:

| Date | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 01st Jan, 2021 | Bohemian |
| 02nd Jan 2021 | Jack |
| 03rd Jan 2021 | John |

Comment: Please show sample table data and expected output.

Comment: Updated question, to include sample table data and expected output

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking for this:

```
Select distinct date, name from note
```

Best regards,Bjarni